# How does a diploid sporophyte form in non-recurrent apomixis?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, reproduction

I came across this definition of non-recurrent apomixis which occurs in angiosperms-

> In non-recurrent apomixis, both the egg-cell and embryo are haploid and embryo is developed directly from an egg-cell without fertilization.

If this is the case, how does a diploid sporophyte develop from the haploid embryo? Are there any examples of the same?

I think most likely it would be by free nuclear divisions, that seems like the best bet, but I'm not sure if that's how it occurs.